# How to edit circle edge in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I edit the edge of the circle to make it for example black with a  dashed thick line weight

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.5, color='r', alpha=0.1))
ax.plot()  
plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: Something like `plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.5, edgecolor='black', facecolor='r', lw=15, ls='--')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[patches.Circle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html) takes linewidth and linestyle as arguments. [Linestyle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_linestyle) has multiple presets and dashes can also be manually configured (length of dash and spacing between the dashes).

[(From the matplotlib documentation)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_linestyle)
[image]

[image]

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(11, 5))
axes = axes.flatten()

axes[0].add_patch(plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.5, facecolor='#c7c7c7', alpha=1, linewidth=3, linestyle='--', edgecolor='black'))
axes[1].add_patch(plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.5, facecolor='#c7c7c7', alpha=1, linewidth=2, linestyle=(0, (8, 3)), edgecolor='black'))
lims = [ax.set_xlim(-0.6, 0.6) for ax in axes]
lims = [ax.set_ylim(-0.6, 0.6) for ax in axes]
```